How to create a dynamically generated Table of Contents (TOC) with page numbers for a merged PDF using iText 5 in Java?
I'm working on a Java project where I use iText 5 to merge multiple PDF files generated by Crystal Reports into a single PDF document. After merging these PDFs, I need to add a dynamically generated Table of Contents (TOC) at the beginning of the document, where each TOC entry includes the title and corresponding page number.
The challenge I'm facing is how to identify the titles and their corresponding page numbers in the merged PDF and then generate the TOC accordingly. What would be the best approach to accomplish this with iText 5?
Here is my code what I have done so far for merging
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextExtractionStrategy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PDFMerge {
    private static final String fileName = "_My Report.pdf";
    private static final String tempDest = "temp_MergePDFs.pdf";
    private static final String finalDest = "3_MergePDFs.pdf";

    public void generateMergedPDF(int fileCount) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(tempDest));
        document.open();

        // Looping through number of files generated and adding their pages to a single temp pdf
        for (int inc = 1; inc <= fileCount; inc++) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inc + fileName);
            int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
                PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                copy.addPage(page);
            }
            reader.close();
        }

        document.close();

        mergeContent();
    }

    // Merging them in the temporary pdf file
    private void mergeContent() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader tempReader = new PdfReader(tempDest);
        Document finalDoc = new Document();
        PdfCopy copyWith = new PdfCopy(finalDoc, new FileOutputStream(finalDest));
        finalDoc.open();

        // Adding the rest of the pages to the pdf
        int totalPages = tempReader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            PdfImportedPage page = copyWith.getImportedPage(tempReader, i);
            copyWith.addPage(page);
        }

        finalDoc.close();
        tempReader.close();
    }
}

Thank you!
